# Can i use webservice.vb for getting the info from gprs and for storing the information into database?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services

I'm developing an ASP.Net web site using VB.Net for receiving data from a device.

The device will send data to the server where the website is placed.

My question is: can I write my script in WebService VB.Net for getting the values from the device and for storing the same information into the web server database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice for that would be to have a separate windows service to poll or respond to I/O interrupts from the device and have that push information into the DB.

Your website would then simply pull that information from the DB and display it.